# Ruby bundler: An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have upgraded my ruby version to ruby ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin19]

When I run bundle to update my gems, I get next error that I have no idea what to do with:

```
    bundle
    Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..............
Fetching https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby
Fetching rake 10.1.0
Installing rake 10.1.0
Fetching i18n 0.6.5
Installing i18n 0.6.5
Fetching minitest 4.7.5
Installing minitest 4.7.5
Fetching multi_json 1.14.1
Installing multi_json 1.14.1
Fetching atomic 1.1.14
Installing atomic 1.1.14 with native extensions
Fetching thread_safe 0.1.3
Installing thread_safe 0.1.3
Fetching tzinfo 0.3.37
Installing tzinfo 0.3.37
Fetching activesupport 4.0.0
Installing activesupport 4.0.0
Fetching builder 3.1.4
Installing builder 3.1.4
Fetching erubis 2.7.0
Installing erubis 2.7.0
Fetching rack 1.5.2
Installing rack 1.5.2
Fetching rack-test 0.6.2
Installing rack-test 0.6.2
Fetching actionpack 4.0.0
Installing actionpack 4.0.0
Fetching mime-types 1.25
Installing mime-types 1.25
Fetching polyglot 0.3.3
Installing polyglot 0.3.3
Fetching treetop 1.4.15
Installing treetop 1.4.15
Fetching mail 2.5.4
Installing mail 2.5.4
Fetching actionmailer 4.0.0
Installing actionmailer 4.0.0
Fetching activemodel 4.0.0
Installing activemodel 4.0.0
Fetching activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Installing activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Fetching arel 4.0.0
Installing arel 4.0.0
Fetching activerecord 4.0.0
Installing activerecord 4.0.0
Fetching addressable 2.3.6
Installing addressable 2.3.6
Fetching gyoku 1.3.1
Installing gyoku 1.3.1
Fetching mini_portile 0.5.3
Installing mini_portile 0.5.3
Fetching nokogiri 1.6.1
Installing nokogiri 1.6.1 with native extensions
Fetching akami 1.3.1
Installing akami 1.3.1
Using bundler 1.17.3
Fetching chronic 0.10.2
Installing chronic 0.10.2
Fetching coffee-script-source 1.6.3
Installing coffee-script-source 1.6.3
Fetching execjs 2.0.1
Installing execjs 2.0.1
Fetching coffee-script 2.2.0
Installing coffee-script 2.2.0
Fetching thor 0.18.1
Installing thor 0.18.1
Fetching railties 4.0.0
Installing railties 4.0.0
Fetching coffee-rails 4.0.0
Installing coffee-rails 4.0.0
Fetching css_parser 1.3.5
Installing css_parser 1.3.5
Fetching hike 1.2.3
Installing hike 1.2.3
Fetching htmlentities 4.3.2
Installing htmlentities 4.3.2
Fetching httpi 2.4.1
Installing httpi 2.4.1
Fetching jbuilder 1.5.1
Installing jbuilder 1.5.1
Fetching jquery-rails 3.0.4
Installing jquery-rails 3.0.4
Fetching json 1.8.1
Installing json 1.8.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/Rober/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator
/Users/Rober/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby -I /Users/Rober/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0 -r ./siteconf20191125-59844-rge3ax.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/Rober/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/Rober/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
    VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                              ^
/Users/Rober/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/intern.h:795:9: note: macro 'rb_str_new' defined here
#define rb_str_new(str, len) RB_GNUC_EXTENSION_BLOCK(   \
        ^
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:11: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long') with an expression of type 'VALUE (const char *,
long)' (aka 'unsigned long (const char *, long)') [-Wint-conversion]
    VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
          ^        ~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:840:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cFixnum'
    } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                        ^
generator.c:842:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cBignum'
    } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                        ^
1 warning and 3 errors generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Rober/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Rober/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.4.0/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sdoc was resolved to 0.3.20, which depends on
    rdoc was resolved to 3.12.2, which depends on
      json
```

Comment: _Following files may not be writable, so sudo is needed_, did you try `sudo bundle install`?

Comment: This is the warning that I get when running with sudo: Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine. After that, I get the same error.

Comment: Upgrade json to >= 2.